# Is it possible to provide credentials for the target Google Cloud Bucket when copying to it in the Java API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

In the below code, I take in an input bucket and blob and an output bucket and blob. The code establishes service account credentials for the blob in the input bucket via the `setCredentials` method. However, there is no mirrored step in the `copyTo` method for the output bucket.

```
  def copy(inBucketName: String,
           inBlobName: String,
           outBucketName: String,
           outBlobName: String) = {

    val storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder
      .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("key.json")))
      .build
      .getService
    val blobId = BlobId.of(inBucketName, inBlobName)
    val blob = storage.get(blobId)
    if (blob != null) {
      val copyWriter = blob.copyTo(outBucketName, outBlobName)
      val copiedBlob = copyWriter.getResult()
    }
  }
```

I'm concerned that this will cause some authentication issues in the future if each bucket has different service credentials. Looking at the `blob.copyTo()` API, I can also pass in a `BlobSourceOptoin object` : `public CopyWriter copyTo(String targetBucket, String targetBlob, BlobSourceOption... options)`. However, I'm failing to see anywhere in `BlobSourceOption` where I could assign credentials. Is this credential assignment for the target bucket necessary? And if so, is there a standard way to set them?

Answer (score 0):

Worked with the below snippet. Credentials is a credential JSON string.

```
val storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder
      .setCredentials(
        ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
          new FileInputStream(credentials)))
      .build
      .getService
```